# ASP.NET Core 2.0 - MySQL Database Connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I`m creating a new ASP.net Core 2.0 MVC WebApplication. I would like to import an existing Database to make use of the data in the WebApp.

In ASP.NET MVC 5 there was an easy way: just add a new Element: "EF 6.x DbContextGenerator". I found out that this is gone in ASP.NET Core 2.0. My following Google search was not successful and thats why im asking you: is there any similar way for ASP.net Core 2.0 to Connect to a existing MySQL Database?

Is the Entity Framework in ASP.net Core 2.0 working like in ASP.net MVC 5?

Answer (score 5):

On MySQL website they recommend MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore. It works with .NET Core 2.0.

Check out this page, I hope it will help you: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework-core.html

Answer (score 3):

Manage Nuget Packages-> search MySql.Data Add project.

[Mysql.Data.Core](https://www.nuget.org/stats/packages/MySql.Data.Core?groupby=Version)

edit `appsetting.json`

```
{
      "ConnectionStrings": {
      "DefaultConnection": 
       "server=localhost;userid=myusername;password=mypassword; 
       database=mydatabase;"
   },
   "Logging": {
       "IncludeScopes": false,
       "LogLevel": {
       "Default": "Warning"
       }
   }
}
```